# Laravel 5 Routing for Subfolders

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel 5. I just want a button to redirect to a page in a subfolder. Here is my code for the button...

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('members.Register') }}" class="btn btn-danger">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
    Click here to register Register
</a>
```

I want the above button to go to a page in a members folder. The below is my code in the routes file. *Note: members is a folder name and register.blade.php is the name of the file inside the members folder*.

```
Route::get('Register', function () {
    return View::make('members.Register');
});
```

Comment: Your question is barely readable, please try and improve and clarify what you're trying to say.

Comment: hi please have a look now. Basically all i want is a button redirection to a page in sub folder.

Comment: Just to clear things up: In Laravel, you don't redirect to a folder, you redirect to a **route**. In your case, its address is `/register` so you would do `URL::to('register')`. Then, inside the route, you can do anything. What you did was **render** a **view** called `register` in the `views/members` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
href="{{ URL::to('members.Register') }}"
```

To

```
href="{{ URL::to('Register') }}"
```

You have specified, the path to be 'Register', not 'members.Register' in

```
Route::get('Register', function() {
    return View::make('members.Register');
});
```

In your resources/views Folder must be a subfolder members, that contains a file Register.php ( or Register.blade.php )

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.I am sorry i am new to laravel my routes file is not working although home page redirection works.

Comment: whats the problem with your routes.php file ?

Comment: HI can you please make a simple redirection for me in which there is a home page and user clicks and goes to different page via routes using  blade.Please sorry for the troubles